# Why library installation in R on Linux seems to be slower than in Windows

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, installation, libraries, r

Just for curiosity, I have dual boot system and in both side I use R, however, regarding to the library installation, I found Linux is way slower than Windows, sometimes also you need to manully install dependencies using `apt install` in Ubuntu and for windows, everything is just smooth and fast.

Comment: Does not sound like a question, more like an observation.

Comment: It is a question, I wonder what's the mechanism that caused this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

R on Windows installs binary (i.e., precompiled) versions of R extension packages (.zip suffix on CRAN). There are also precompiled packages for macOS on CRAN (.tgz).
If you use `install.packages()` on Linux, the package is build from the sources, which requires a proper development setup (compilers, development libraries, etc).
See also `?install.packages`.